# Build programmatically - The "TransformTemplates" task was not loaded from assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, t4

I am trying to build some applications programmatically, using **Microsoft.Build.Execution**, however I have encountered the following error:

> The "TransformTemplates" task was not loaded from assembly C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> \2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.Build.Tasks.dll.
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core,
> Version = 15.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken =
> b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
> the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is
> correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available and
> that the task contains a public class that implements
> Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask

My code implemented:

```
Dictionary<string, string> globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { "RebuildT4Templates" , "true" },
                        { "VSToolsPath", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" },
                        { "LangVersion", "6" },
                        { "ToolsVersion", "15.0" },
                        { "VisualStudioVersion", "15.0" }
                    };
var manager = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager;
var buildLoggger = new InMemoryBuildLogger();
var buildParameters = new BuildParameters() { Loggers = new[] { buildLoggger } };
var buildRequestData = new BuildRequestData(csProj, globalProperties, null, new[] { "Rebuild" }, null);
var buildResult = manager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequestData);
```

.Csproj file that I'm trying to build.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <!-- Run the Transform task at the start of every build -->
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <!-- -->
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <!-- Transform every template every time -->
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <!-- add AFTER import for $(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets -->
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <T4ParameterValues Include="BuildConfiguration">
      <Value>$(Configuration)</Value>
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </T4ParameterValues>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CreateT4ItemListsForMSBuildCustomTool" BeforeTargets="CreateT4ItemLists" AfterTargets="SelectItemsForTransform">
    <ItemGroup>
      <T4Transform Include="@(CreateT4ItemListsInputs)" Condition="'%(CreateT4ItemListsInputs.Generator)' == 'MSBuild:TransformAll'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? it seems that MSBuild does not have the necessary dependencies to build T4Template

Comment: How did you reference `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll` in your project? What is the assembly dll version of it?  Did you try to use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll`?

Answer (score 0):

**As a suggestion**, I think you should reference the dll by right-click on the **References**-->**Add Reference**-->**Assemblies**-->**Extensions**-->find `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll` and then reference it.

==============================

**Update 1**

**Maybe** you should update your **VS2017** is it is not the latest version and the new version in my side uses the `15.1.0.0` of that dll.

So I am not sure whether your old VS2017 uses the `15.0.0.0` version and it uses 15.0.0.0 under the `msbuild.exe.config` file. If not, you should update your **VS2017**.

**1)** Or add bindingredirect on `app.config` or `web.config` file:

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" publicKeyToken="xxxxx"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```

**2)** check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.config` and make sure that there is the same binding redirect like the above for `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core`.

**3)** Or if not, you should try to install [Microsoft.Build 15.1.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/15.1.548)nuget package and [Microsoft.Build.Runtime 15.1.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Runtime/15.1.548) nuget package. **Then**, add binding redirect for them.

Comment: Even adding this reference, the error still remains. From what I saw the reference to 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core' that I'm referring to is version 15.1.0.0 and not 15.0.0.0 which is necessary ... I didn't find this binary in version 15.0.0.0 on my machine

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Since you used `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core 15.1.0.0`, I think you should try to add the `bindredirect` to `15.1.0.0`. Please check `update 1`.